# Add dataframe column from other dataframe if condition applies

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

My problem is the following: I have two dataframes that vary in length. Both have the colum "title" in common and look something like this:

```
df1:  
idn  title         ISBN         other_stuff 
343  some title    3847832342   ahfsdfasjdfs
351  other title   9785482733   asfdjkajskfdfd


df2:
idn  title         ISBN         important      other_stuff 
444  some title    633847347    interesting    dakjsfdlfeihaiwfh
566  some title    242343243                   4wkhashfuihwauehfa
545  further title 543545455    r3434
```

What I want is to look at the column "title" in the first dataframe (df1) and check against the "title" column in the second dataframe (df2). If they match (as in the case with "some title", I then want to add a column to df1 that contains the values from the column "important" in df2.

I have now tried the following:

```
df1['new_column'] = np.where(df1['title'] != df2['title'], df2['important'], 'N/A')
```

But I receive an error message:
`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

So far, I have tried resetting the indexes of both dataframes as well as dropping them, but this hasn't helped. I am not sure how to fix this and why this occurs - maybe the problem is that I have two hits for "title" in df2? If so, how do I solve this? I would be happy to just use the first hit where there's an entry in "important" and ignore all other hits for "some title" afterwards, but am not sure how to do that - if at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.merge`. [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) is the documentation.

Ideally, it should work like so:

`df1.merge(df2[['title', 'important']], left_on='title', right_on='title')`

Comment: Thank you, this works, but I do end up with a much longer dataframe in the end. Is there a way to merge or append the dataframe so that I end up with a dataframe that is basically df1 with an additional column for "important"? I hope I am explaining it okayish...

Comment: @ssp24 It shouldn't return a longer dataframe. Maybe try setting `how = 'left'`

Comment: Thank you, I think this hopefully solved it! :)